# Crystal report shows all records of table though specific records assigned to report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am developing a windows application. I am using Crystal Reports and it runs perfectly. My problem is, Crystal report not showing records as per records returned by query.

I have written the query which fetches the records, as per the user input. But when I bind the collection to reports, it shows all the records which are present in the database and not the records which I have in collection.

One more thing, Its working perfectly before adding the parameter field. If I use below line of code:

```
cr.SetDataSource(oBatches)
```

Its working, shows the only records which are in collection, but prompts to enter parameter manually. Below is the code.

```
Private Sub btnLoadBatch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLoadBatch.Click
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim cr As New crMonthwiseBatch
        Dim oBatches As New Batches
        Dim Month As Integer = dtFrom.Value.Date.Month
        Dim StartDateForBatch As Date = New DateTime(dtBatchStartFromMonth.Value.Year, dtBatchStartFromMonth.Value.Month, "1")
        Dim DaysinMonths As Integer = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(dtBatchStartFromMonth.Value.Year, dtBatchStartFromMonth.Value.Month)
        Dim EndDateForBatch = StartDateForBatch.AddDays(DaysinMonths)

        ----->      oBatches.LoadByQuery("CreatedDate >= #" + StartDateForBatch + "# and CreatedDate <= #" + EndDateForBatch + "#")

        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = "Batch List of Month " + MonthName(dtBatchStartFromMonth.Value.Month) + " " + dtBatchStartFromMonth.Value.Year.ToString
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cr.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("MonthName")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
        CrystalReportViewerMonthwiseBatch.ReportSource = cr
        CrystalReportViewerMonthwiseBatch.Refresh()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        MessageBox.Show("Error :- " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not setting the DataSource of the report, after assigning the data object (as marked in the code below) its working fine.

```
Private Sub btnShowCustomer_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowCustomer.Click
    Try
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
        Dim cr As New rptDatewiseCustomerReport
        Dim oCustomers As New Customers
        Dim StartDate As DateTime
        Dim EndDate As DateTime
        StartDate = dtFrom.Value.Date.AddDays(-1)
        EndDate = dtTO.Value.Date.AddDays(1)
        oCustomers.LoadByQuery("CreatedDate >= #" + StartDate.Date + "# and CreatedDate <= #" + EndDate.Date + "#")

        'Added Line below---->        
        cr.SetDataSource(oCustomers)

        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim DatetimeTest As String = dtFrom.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy").ToString + " To " + dtTO.Value.Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy").ToString()

        crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = DatetimeTest
        crParameterFieldDefinitions = cr.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
        crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("paraFromDate")
        crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
        crParameterValues.Clear()
        crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
        crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
        CrystalReportViewer2.ReportSource = cr
        CrystalReportViewer2.Refresh()
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
        MessageBox.Show("Error :- " + ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
End Sub
```